# product of two number in a array

Tags: algorithm

Given a array of n distinct integer. Find all pairs of x,y in the array such that z(given) = x * y...do it without sorting and in a most efficient manner..

[edit] Integer are within range of int i.e 0-65536 and numbers are non negative if that helps.
Dont want to sort coz it will take a lot of time. Storage space is not a issue.

Comment: I don't like questions with constraints like "don't use sorting", "don't use loops"... :-\

Comment: Its now a homework for god's sake. I am working in a company. I have to find pairs needed for my project. I wanted to find the effiecient solution available

Comment: @honeybadger, How big are the integers? Easily Factorerd?

Comment: @stole by sorting i will waste hell lot of time which i dont want

Comment: @stole Integer are within range of int i.e 0-65536 and numbers are non negative if that helps

Comment: why this question is rated -1. I dont get it? @birryree I think i made the question clear

Comment: @honeybadger, apologies if I offended, it just read like some of my old assignments did.

Comment: @honeybadger - I say that when my homework sense blows up, or if a question sounds like a regurgitation of problems that sound like homework.

Comment: ok I think we should now concentrate on question and not on what we said to each other :-) and i think if we breeak our work into smaller chunk some part of it may look like a homework. Afterall college studies is not just a waste of time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is linear time hash based solution:

```
Let hash be an array of size 65537 initilized to 0.

foreach element ele in Array

    if ele != 0
        hash[product/ele] = ele
    end-if

    if hash[ele] != 0 AND ele * hash[ele] == product
        print ele, product/ele
    end-if

end-foreach
```

Comment: The second loop can be merged into the first one...i think. also this will print both `a*b` and `b*a`....

Comment: @stOle: Thanks for pointing. printing distinct pairs is left as HW for OP.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any super efficient ways of doing this. The best I can think of is O(n^2):

Have an auxiliary function that takes a  number (a) and a list, and goes through every element (b) checking a*b = z and saving the pair if it is.

Go through every element of your original list, and if a particular element (x) divides z (ie z % x = 0) then send x and the remainder of the list after x to the auxiliary function.

UPDATE:

I'm giving an O(n^2) solution because the question did not specify *unique* pairs. If only unique pairs are desired, this should be added to the question. Also, my solution assumes the order of pairs doesn't matter, which is another detail that should be clarified.

Comment: No o(n^2) is out of the question. I will prefer to sort than doing this.

Comment: @st0le you're absolutely right, I shouldn't have critiqued the wording without actually reading it carefully first

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the array...if an element `x` can divide `z` (ie `z % x == 0`), check if it's other factor `y=(z/x)` exists in the HashTable....

If it does, then you found a pair...else just add it to the hashTable and continue...